# multiple conditional boolean logic Python

Tags: python

Can I get a tip on a better way of Boolean conditional logic in Python? I am trying to return a True or False based on the `current_time` being between a `starttime` & `endtime` as well as other Boolean logic to check if the `current_day` that is datetime weekday number is a weekend or weekday.

Is a function seemed best fit for this? Any tips help I am having an issue where if `Weekends` or `Weekdays` are both `False` that means the event is disabled or if the `current_time` is not between `starttime` & `endtime` the event will also be disabled, so `Return False`

```
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()
current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M")
print("Current Time is ", current_time)

# To Get the Week Number
current_day = datetime.today().weekday()
print("Current Weekday Number is ", current_day)   


data1 = {'setpoint': '366', 'Weekdays': 'True', 'Weekends': 'True', 'starttime': '02:40', 'endtime': '22:40'}
data2 = {'setpoint': '366', 'Weekdays': 'False', 'Weekends': 'True', 'starttime': '02:40', 'endtime': '22:40'}
data3 = {'setpoint': '366', 'Weekdays': 'True', 'Weekends': 'False', 'starttime': '02:40', 'endtime': '03:40'}
data4 = {'setpoint': '366', 'Weekdays': 'False', 'Weekends': 'False', 'starttime': '02:40', 'endtime': '22:40'}



def condition_checker(data,current_time,current_day):
    between_time = data['starttime'] <= current_time <= data['endtime']
    #print("between_time", between_time)

    disabled = data['Weekends'] == False and data['Weekdays'] == False
    print("disabled is", disabled)
    
    weekday_rules = current_day in [0,1,2,3,4]
    #print("weekday_rules", weekday_rules)

    weekend_rules = current_day in [5,6]
    #print("weekend_rules", weekend_rules)
    
    if between_time and not disabled and weekday_rules or between_time and not disabled and weekend_rules:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

data1 seems to work Ok:

```
# True weekend/weekdays and on start/end times 
condition_checker(data1,current_time,current_day)
```

returns

```
disabled is False
True
```

data2 seems to work Ok:

```
# True on Weekends and start/end times
condition_checker(data2,current_time,current_day)
```

returns

```
disabled is False
True
```

data3 seems to work Ok:

```
# False on times
condition_checker(data3,current_time,current_day)
```

returns

```
disabled is False
False
```

This is where my logic isnt working, should be false on `disabled`
data4 NOT working

```
# False on disabled
condition_checker(data4,current_time,current_day)
```

returns

```
disabled is False
True
```

Comment: I'm having some trouble understandign what you actually want. Can you clarify what `weekday_rules` and `weekend_rules` are supposed to do?

Comment: Note that your `if ...` condition seems to be missing parentheses. Did you mean `(between_time and not disabled and weekday_rules) or (between_time and not disabled and weekend_rules)`? If so, (and AFAIU `weekday_rules` is simply `not weekend_rules`), this will boil down to simply `if (between_time and not disabled): return True; else: return False`, or `return between_time and not disabled`

Comment: Your dictionaries have "True" and "False" as strings. Your `disabled` statement is comparing these with boolean `True` and `False`.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I am just trying to verify if current weekday number is a weekend or weekday as well as if the dictionary keys are True too. If they are False, then return False

Comment: @not_speshal is there a better way to do this? I realize its strings

Comment: Maybe I just need to change to `str(False)` didnt realize this...

Comment: Or just "False"? But it would be better to change your dictionary values to boolean like: `data1 = {'setpoint': '366', 'Weekdays': True, 'Weekends': True, 'starttime': '02:40', 'endtime': '22:40'}`

Comment: This works, `disabled = data['Weekends'] == str(False) and data['Weekdays'] == str(False)` thanks for pointing out `strings`

Comment: @not_speshal thanks for the tips if you posted an answer Ill hit the green check. Ill also look into changing the dictionary values to Boolean as you recommended...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing strings with boolean values in your function. I would change the dictionaries to hold boolean `True`/`False` like so:

```
data1 = {'setpoint': '366', 'Weekdays': True, 'Weekends': True, 'starttime': '02:40', 'endtime': '22:40'}
data2 = {'setpoint': '366', 'Weekdays': False, 'Weekends': True, 'starttime': '02:40', 'endtime': '22:40'}
data3 = {'setpoint': '366', 'Weekdays': True, 'Weekends': False, 'starttime': '02:40', 'endtime': '03:40'}
data4 = {'setpoint': '366', 'Weekdays': False, 'Weekends': False, 'starttime': '02:40', 'endtime': '22:40'}
```

Alternatively (less preferable but also works), you can change your function to check against `string` values:

```
def condition_checker(data,current_time,current_day):
    between_time = data['starttime'] <= current_time <= data['endtime']
    disabled = data['Weekends'] == "False" and data['Weekdays'] == "False"
    print("disabled is", disabled)
    
    weekday_rules = current_day in [0,1,2,3,4]
    weekend_rules = current_day in [5,6]
    
    if between_time and not disabled and weekday_rules or between_time and not disabled and weekend_rules:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Any chance you could give me a tip on how to do that? Still learning alot here... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68289246/sqlite-boolean-operators

Comment: How to do what? Copy-paste the dictionaries I have in my answer and use your original function. Notice how the `True` and `False` values are not in quotes.

Comment: The data comes from HTML form input tables

Comment: In that case, it's better to change your function to compare with `=="True"`. I'd rather not change input data.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help keep as a String comparison....